# What database do i choose if I need to make an inventory system

Tags: sql, database

I need to develop an inventory system(Windows application). 
This INV System will be installed on the HQ(always online) and on different sites(locations) which works off line and goes online only once to transfer the data to the server on HQ.

Which database(free)(huge data) can be used is my first question. 
Secondly, how to update daily changes made on local database to database on server.

Comment: This question is too broad and subject to many details. You can't ask people to design an architecture or choose tools for you. You should do your research, and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Express for this. For transfer of data you can either run scripts in SQL or create packages in SSIS that will pull data from sites. These package can be a scheduled jobs or can be run manually.